# SUBSTRING_INDEX' error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This code is executing fine in MySQL :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(empid, '-', 1) 
FROM employees
```

But it throws this error in SQL Server :

> 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I don't want to use where clause.

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is not a built in function in SQL Server. What is your question?

Comment: how can i modify the query to use it in MS SQL server

Comment: For this particular example you can use something like: `SELECT LEFT(empid, CHARINDEX('-', empid, 1) - 1) FROM employees` - This is not quite comparable to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (hence a comment not an answer), but it should work for your case.

Comment: i am getting following error :
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: now getting following error :Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: `SELECT LEFT(empid, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', empid, 1) - 1, -1), LEN(empID))) FROM employees`

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select (case when empid like '%-%'
             then left(empid, charindex('-', empid) - 1)
             else empid
        end)
from employees;
```